# SKI transform, how to program in a functional language

Tags: functional-programming, prolog, lambda-calculus

I am facing the following Prolog code. The expression [X]>>Y stands
for the lambda expression lambda X.Y. The code eliminates the lambda
and gives a combinatory expression over S, K and I:

```
convert([X]>>Y,'I') :- X==Y, !.
convert([X]>>Y,apply('K',Y)) :- var(Y), !.
convert([X]>>([Y]>>Z),R) :-
     convert([Y]>>Z,H), convert([X]>>H,R).
convert([X]>>apply(Y,Z),apply(apply('S',S),T)) :-
     convert([X]>>Y,S), convert([X]>>Z,T).
convert([_]>>Y,apply('K',Y)).
```

Here is an example how it works:

```
 ?- convert([X]>>([Y]>>apply(Y,X)),R).
 R = apply(apply('S', apply(apply('S', apply('K', 'S')), 
  apply('K', 'I'))), apply(apply('S', apply('K', 'K')), 'I'))
```

Suppose I would like to code the same **conversion** in Haskell, ML, or 
the like. How can I do this? Can I use the lambda expressions available
in the functional programming language directly? Or do I have to 
regress to some meta programming facilities?

Best Regards

P.S.: The code above is not the SKI conversion that leads to very short
SKI expressions. Better code is possible that checks for occurence of
the bound variable in the lambda expression body.

Comment: After posting this question I found the following interesting paper:  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs242/readings/backus.pdf . I draw the conclusion for my conversion purpose I would need a FFP (Formal Functional Language). So might the real FFP please stand up!

Comment: From the answers and comments so far, I conclude that ML, Haskell do not integrate FFP seamlessly. And on the other hand Lisp, Scheme, etc.. do integrate FFP seamlessly. Can we say that when it has seamless FFP, it is a Lisp alike? Or is there a third option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prolog code can be translated almost verbatim into a pattern matching of ML or Haskell. Of course you'd need to define your own ADT for lambda expressions. And for the most optimal set of combinators and conversion for that set I'd recommend to refer to [http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Programming-International-Computer-Science/dp/0201192497](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201192497)

Comment: If you want to transform the expressions of your host language, you'd need some sort of metaprogramming capabilities. E.g., in Template Haskell you'd have an access to an AST - but expect to implement quite a complicated transform, as Haskell is much more complex than a simple untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: @Jan Burse, the book I've mentioned talks specifically about compilation techniques for functional languages, and there is a whole chapter about the combinators-based implementation.

Comment: There is at least one Lisp-like language wich does such a transform: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dslengine/

Comment: If you want to operate on an AST of your language you've got no choice but to use some kind of metaprogramming. An external preprocessor is an option - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camlp4 for example. Lisp macros and Template Haskell transformers are just of another kind of metaprogramming. P.S. - what you're doing in Prolog is an example of a metaprogramming as well.

Comment: @Jan Burse, what do you mean by doing metaprogramming "directly"? Of course you can read S-expression (say, a quoted one) and transform it, but you'd need a macro in order to pass your transformed code to a compiler. And you'd need a macro in order to transform a part of a "normal" code, not a quoted constant (the latter is pretty much equivalent to defining your own ADT, to which you opposed).

Comment: @Jan Burse, eval is supported by many Lisp implementations, but there is no point in a dynamic evaluation of a code that can be translated in a compilation time. Any way, using eval with a dynamically generated input is a form of metaprogramming as well. You won't get away from it.

Comment: @Jan Burse, the fact that functional languages are based on lambda expressions does not mean that expression trees could be available dynamically in a runtime. It is only possible for some interpreted languages. All the decent functional languages compilers eliminates source ASTs long before the code is executed. For more information on how functional languages are implemented you'd need to either read the book mentioned earlier or a more up-to-date book http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/

Comment: I am just looking at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/meta-haskell/meta-haskell.pdf to get a feeling how direct Template Haskell is. The [| |] looks quite direct to me, but there is a lot of other stuff as well. They have a reference to MetaML as an inspirational source.

Comment: Prolog has also compilers that generate code that has nothing to do with the original terms and the original terms are thrown away. But I can switch this off anytime with the directive "dynamic", and then my original terms get fully accessible via the predicate "clause" besides the compiled code. It is only a matter whether, where and how the AST is kept. In Prolog and also in the old Lisp there was kind of a zero impedance mismatch between the AST and the usual objects in the corresponding language. I just wondered whether this is still the case for functional languages.

Comment: @Jan Burse, Prolog always operates on terms directly, even a WAM-compiled one. Any other term rewriting language will have the same runtime metaprogramming capabilities, no matter how is it compiled and executed. But the availability of an AST, and the "code is data" paradigm is not a part of a definition of what functional languages are, it is more a property of dynamic languages and term rewriting languages. Lisp is somewhere in the middle - it is both static and dynamic, with a compiler available in runtime and a runtime available in a compilation time.

Comment: It looks that Template Haskell requires an interleaving of compile-time and runtime. The quote is:    "Hence, type checking is intimately interleaved with (compile-time)
execution."  Its in section 7 of the meta-haskell.pdf paper, after an explanation of an example that shows this. Very interesting.

Comment: I am not sure how you want to exclude functional programming from the class of term rewriting languages. To define term rewriting for a functional languages I would define something like eval((s t)) --> reduce(eval(s),eval(t)), reduce((lambda x.s),t) -->  etc..

Comment: @Jan Burse, operational semantics of a functional language is not necessarily equal to the term-rewriting denotational semantics of the lambda calculus. Static languages does not have any eval functions. As for TH - yes, it is somewhat similar to Lisp, as its macros are just normal Haskell functions which can use any of the available Haskell libraries.

Comment: What I admire in Lisp macros is that from the outside they just look like normal functions. What about Template Haskell, do you know by chance whether things like [| |] are they based on normal operator definitions, so that TH is only semantic extension, or is it also a syntactical extension?

Comment: BTW: The dslengine looks quite impressive. But general question, arent combinator based engines quite dead right now, nobody using them anymore?

Comment: @Jan Burse: yes, combinator- and supercombinator-based compilation is not used any longer, as it is inferior on a stock hardware. All of the modern lazy functional languages are compiled into STGM - see the S. P. Jones book I've mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use lamdba expressions. In Haskell:

```
i x = x
k x = \y -> x
s x y z = x z $ y z

r = s (s (k s) (k i)) (s (k k) i)

-- r 3 (+5) -> 8
```

(note that I didn't know of SKI up to know, this snippet is a direct conversion of the definitions on Wikipedia into Haskell; it works, but do check if it's conceptually right)

Comment: @abesto: Thank you very much of posting the definition of S, K and I and verifying that the conversion example I gave was correct. But I would like to see a program that does for example the following: Input \x -> \y -> y x, Output: s (s (k s) (k i)) (s (k k) i)

Comment: Oh. Looks like i missed the point of your question then, sorry.

Comment: BTW: What is the operator $ doing? Is this the Owl? Did you use it to save parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, the only point is to use less parens. To illustrate:
(a x y z = x $ y z) and (b x y z = x (y z)) are the same functions.

Comment: Also, S = (<*>) and K = pure in ((->) r). So you get SKI by including id in ((->) r).

Comment: @danportin: Hi, I don't understand what you are saying. It starts with the syntax, what kind of syntax is this, what is the meaning of S = (<*>)? Can you elaborate a little bit.

Comment: (<*>) and pure are the functions in the type class Applicative, which are the combinators S and K in combinatory logic. If you include the identity function id, you get SKI.

Comment: Ok, got it. Found a definition here: http://users.skynet.be/jyp/html/base/Control-Applicative.html , and by ((->) r) you are refering to the transformer output I am seeking... Any special advocation how to dynamically generate r? How do parser generators work in Haskell (I just read that Applicative was introduced for parsers)?

Comment: One quite short SKI term for: \x -> \y -> y x. Is the following term: s (k (s i)) k.